# One macro running , the other does not

Tags: excel, vba

I am importing currency data from a website on a **click event**.

The import works and its called by this code:

```
Option Explicit

 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F13")) Is Nothing Then
        Call GetCurrency
    End If
End If
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F14")) Is Nothing Then
        Call UpdateCurrency
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

If the cell F13 is clicked, the `GetCurrency` macro runs, imports the data, wonderful.

*But clicking F14 causes nothing.*

The update currency macro looks like this

```
Sub UpdateCurrency()

Range("N15").Value = Range("I19").Value
Range("N14").Value = Range("I26").Value
Range("N16").Value = Range("I22").Value

 End Sub
```

This should just update some other cells in order to make another formula work properly. Question is, why does clicking the cell F14 not run the UpdateCurrency function?

Comment: I tested your code and it works.. Have you got the code in the worksheet? If it's in a module it wont work

Comment: I have it in a sheet. So F14 does update the initial values if you set H14-H17 to zero or something? This is very odd

Comment: HM, now it work, no other change made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think you need to change the if statements a bit.

```
Option Explicit

 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Target = Range("F13") Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F13")) Is Nothing Then
            Call GetCurrency
        End If
     Else
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F14")) Is Nothing Then
                Call UpdateCurrency
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```